# how to send error message to client?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, sequelize.js, passport.js

I am using passport with local strategy .but I want to send message and status when `credential` is not match or (`user is not exit is DB`)

here is code

**router.js**

```
const passport = require('passport');
const passportConfig = require('../passport')
const passportSignIn = passport.authenticate('local', { session: false });

router.route('/login',)
    .post(passportSignIn,controller.login)
```

**on controller file**

```
 login: async (req, res, next) => {
        console.log(req.body);
        res.json({status:200})

    }
```

**passport.js**

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email'
}, async (email, password, done) => {

    const user = await db.User.findOne({where: {email: email}});
    if (!user) {
        return done(null, false,{message:"No user exit"});
    }
    const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.dataValues.password);
    console.log(isMatch, 'isMatch');
    if (!isMatch) {
        return done(null, false);
    }

    // Otherwise, return the user
    done(null, user);

}))
```

Client code

when user click on `login` button it goes to `/login` path first it goes to `passportSignIn` function or below function.

```
 `new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email'
}, async (email, password, done) => {`
```

now if user not found I want to send this message on the client as the response ("No user exit")

```
return done(null, false,{message:"No user exit"});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to update your login controller, like so:

```
login: (req, res, next) => {
        console.log(req.body);
        passport.authenticate('yourStrategy', function(err, user, info) {
            if (err) {
              return res.status(500).json("Internal Server Error");
            }
            if (!user) {
              // This 'info' variable below would be - { message: "No user exit" }
              // as you passed in the done() callback as the third param
              return res.status(404).json(info.message);
            }
        }
      }
```

Comment: can I use asyn await here

Comment: Sure you can! Try for yourself and let me know if it does/doesn't work. :)

Comment: your function is working fine can you please tell me how can I acheive this using async await

Comment: Why do you want to use async? Any specific reason? :/

Comment: my controller is already async so i will use await here instead of callback

Comment: Actually, async/await is for promises but passport still uses the traditional callback method. There is a thread open on passport's Github to support promises in passport. See here: https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/issues/536 . Long story short, you can not do that for now. Also, please upvote (+1) my answer if you found my answers helpful. :)